# Convert PayPal Time/Date Day Month Year

Tags: php

I have a db which stores the PayPal payment_date in the usual paypal format - HH:MM:SS Mmm DD, YYYY PDT (ie 15:48:34 Apr 10, 2012 PDT). I want to display it when pulled down in recordset as 10 April 2012.

Having some troubles. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: $query_vipdetails = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%d/%b/%Y') as payment_date FROM names WHERE vipname = 'ABC' AND paid = 'Completed' ORDER BY payment_date ASC";

Comment: Not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First try to extract date part from  payment_date http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Need a bit more help/guidance. Sorry. Example?

Comment: Try this:
$query_vipdetails = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(payment_date), '%d/%b/%Y') as payment_date FROM names WHERE vipname = 'ABC' AND paid = 'Completed' ORDER BY payment_date ASC"

Comment: Just tried that. Nothing shows for payment_date at all? blank?

Comment: I think the format paypal use is not the right format to work out the date?

Comment: What happens if you try the query with DATE() function only?

Comment: Decided to change date format before put into db. Worked out simplier, then can just use normal Select. Thanks for help.